Are both integration test and unit test needed in all cases in Spring Boot?
I have a Spring Boot backend where i run integration tests for my controllers (endpoints) and unit tests for my service methods. For some endpoints there are just simple service calls that are returned the same way the service returns the data.
Is it best practice to create just an integration test to test the endpoint, create just a unit test to test the service method or should I add both?

You could also create an test to test the integration between the Spring Framework (http handling), your controller and the service layer. Testing is a highly opinionated topic, with no clear answer. It is really hard to tell what to test and what to stub and what is a unit actually? A class or only parts of a class or even many classes with the same responsibility? As a starter, I can recommend this article: https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html

What do you want to achieve:
Test the system's behavior, so that you can deploy and develop your system with confidence. If you create tests, while developing your business code, you should know, through your tests, that the behaviour of the code hasn't changed.
Let's first analyze what you have:

A controller class with presentation logic (presentation layer)
A service class with business logic (application layer)
The Spring Application Context (3rd party framework)

Concerns:

If you only test the behaviour of your controller or your service (Unit Test), who guarantees you, that both components interact together as planned?
If you see the controller and service as one unit and test them together (Unit Test... wait a minute... isn't this already an integration test, since you integrate different layers of your application. This is already opinionated.), then your test setup can get quite complicated if you want to test all the difference scenarios.
Should I load Springs application context to test the behaviour of my API (this could be called an integration test since a client is integrating with our system under test)?
If I test, what should I test and what should I stub away (with e.g. Mockito)
etc.

Answer:
As you see, there are many concerns and no clear answer to your question. If I had to give a clear answer to your question, I would do the following:

Load the application context and test your API endpoint with mockMVC and therefore also the behaviour of your controller.
Test the behaviour of your interface of your service without loading the application context (it is not needed here, since your business logic should work without the Spring Framework).

The downside is, that you have no test scenario, where you test everything together, but as always in life, there is no right and wrong but just something in between and you have to choose the path.

My answer is if you are not confident about a certain part of the code, then write as many tests as possible. Integration testing is not just for testing Endpoints, and unit testing is not just for testing services.
You need to understand what integration tests, unit tests are, and why you should write these two types of tests. Integration testing executes the functions of multiple modules together. Because there are many functions involved, many conditions need to be prepared (such as databases, initial data), and the execution time is long; unit testing tests a specific method. Integration testing focuses on the whole, unit testing focuses on the parts.
It is recommended that you read books related to test-driven development, and you will have a better understanding of writing these two types of tests.
